# Drawing random numbers and advancing the bit generator yields different results

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to advance my NumPy random number generator to mimic drawing n random numbers. However, when I compare the state of the bit generator after advancing n numbers with simply drawing n numbers, the results differ after some point.

I know that some random numbers might require to advance the state multiple times but I find it odd that the results match for the first 40-50 drawn numbers and then diverge.

I am trying to use advance because at some times I have to draw random numbers to keep reproducing the same results although for some use-cases I already know that I don't use the numbers. In this case, I want to simply (and fast) advance the random number generator but ensuring that all the numbers drawn remain the same.

How can I ensure reproducability and still use features like advance?

If I use a random number generator from `numpy`, I compare the state of the `bit_generator` for the cases when I advance 10 deltas at a time with drawing the same number of random variable (`standard_normal`) at a time. After few iterations, the `rng.bit_generator.state` diverges. I don't know why because I would expect it do diverge instantly or never.

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(2024)
s = rng.bit_generator.state

step = 10
num = 5

# Draw Random numbers using standard normal variable

rng.bit_generator.state = s

x = list()

for i in range(num):
    rng.standard_normal(step)
    x.append(rng.bit_generator.state['state']['state'])
    print('{i:3d} - {state:40d} {inc:40d}'.format(i=i, **rng.bit_generator.state['state']))

# Reset state and advance random number generator
rng.bit_generator.state = s

y = list()

for i in range(num):
    rng.bit_generator.state = rng.bit_generator.advance(step).state
    y.append(rng.bit_generator.state['state']['state'])
    print('{i:3d} - {state:40d} {inc:40d}'.format(i=i, **rng.bit_generator.state['state']))
```

The output looks like this for me. The results differ for iteration 2, i.e. the state is different.

```
  0 -  317319928805135160732659717497650841180  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  1 -  152261761237047187080279356346465986730  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  2 -   12941317612297752247903241541248335614  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  3 -  167375039976652124381293896870728401724  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  4 -   78535979019656695810700673044059278986  263843294879837360010514471918415607657

  0 -  317319928805135160732659717497650841180  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  1 -  152261761237047187080279356346465986730  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  2 -  262244773524709030991986015855808125320  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  3 -  174718512225906865463277455530823048310  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  4 -  213819718814773627130094102456555149556  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
```

Comment: You are printing a variable `state` with this code that I don't see defined.  Likewise with `inc`.

Comment: Never mind, you're using features of `format` that I've never seen before.

Comment: In the first loop you're using `rng.standard_normal(step)`, in the second one you're using `rng.bit_generator.state = rng.bit_generator.advance(step).state`. Seems like that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you assuming that `advance` does the same as generating a sample of a given type>

```
In [715]: rng=np.random.default_rng()

In [716]: timeit rng.bit_generator.advance(1000)
2.66 µs ± 5.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Uniform and normal take different times, suggesting something different in how they are generated:

```
In [717]: timeit rng.random(1000)
10.2 µs ± 9.81 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [718]: timeit rng.standard_normal(1000)
19.3 µs ± 41.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

`advance` docs says:

```
Advancing a RNG updates the underlying RNG state as-if a given
number of calls to the underlying RNG have been made. In general
there is not a one-to-one relationship between the number output
random values from a particular distribution and the number of
draws from the core RNG.
```

`uniform` is the simpler distribution, taking less time, and more likely to have a one-to-one relation with the `advance`:

```
In [727]: rng = np.random.default_rng(2024)
     ...: s = rng.bit_generator.state
    
In [728]: rng.bit_generator.state = s
     ...: for i in range(5):
     ...:     rng.bit_generator.state = rng.bit_generator.advance(10).state
     ...:     print('{i:3d} - {state:40d} {inc:40d}'.format(i=i, **rng.bit_generator.state['state']))
     ...:     
  0 -  317319928805135160732659717497650841180  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  1 -  152261761237047187080279356346465986730  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  2 -  262244773524709030991986015855808125320  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  3 -  174718512225906865463277455530823048310  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  4 -  213819718814773627130094102456555149556  263843294879837360010514471918415607657

In [730]: rng.bit_generator.state = s
     ...: for i in range(5):
     ...:     rng.standard_normal(10)
     ...:     print('{i:3d} - {state:40d} {inc:40d}'.format(i=i, **rng.bit_generator.state['state']))
     ...:     
  0 -  317319928805135160732659717497650841180  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  1 -  152261761237047187080279356346465986730  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  2 -   12941317612297752247903241541248335614  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  3 -  167375039976652124381293896870728401724  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  4 -   78535979019656695810700673044059278986  263843294879837360010514471918415607657

In [731]: rng.bit_generator.state = s
     ...: for i in range(5):
     ...:     rng.random(10)
     ...:     print('{i:3d} - {state:40d} {inc:40d}'.format(i=i, **rng.bit_generator.state['state']))
     ...:     
  0 -  317319928805135160732659717497650841180  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  1 -  152261761237047187080279356346465986730  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  2 -  262244773524709030991986015855808125320  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  3 -  174718512225906865463277455530823048310  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
  4 -  213819718814773627130094102456555149556  263843294879837360010514471918415607657
```

`ramdom` does match the `advance`, `standard_normal` does not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After looking into the code of the random number generation, there is a few percent chance to use more than one state for standard normal. That explains why it matches for the first two iterations in the loop but then diverges. For uniform numbers, there is a one-to-one relationship. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ac8b7ac9e1b47bfc8211ca2895086030e7f71ed4/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L137